# How to use pytest and a common spark session for all tests?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, pytest

I would like to set up a logic of tests in my project, but I am facing an issue with spark.
Consider several tests that are all using a spark session to read data, perform some processing and collecting it as a pandas.DataFrame object.

The problem I am facing is due to conflicts. Anytime I try to access to some columns, I get a KeyError exception, and my tests fail.

My conftest.py looks like :

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def spark_session(request):
    # some code to create a spark config `conf`
    spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

    yield spark

    if "spark-warehouse" in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        shutil.rmtree("./spark-warehouse", ignore_errors=True)

    spark.stop()
```

In any test_*.py files, you have a function which aims to load data with the spark session :

```py
# import some dependencies

def get_data(spark_session):
    spark_context = spark_session.sparkContext
    sql_context = SQLContext(spark_context)
    data = sql_context.read.parquet("data/expected.parquet")
    return data

# some tests
```

I add that I don't want to use unittest, only pytest, for some reasons.

Can someone help me find a solution to this issue ? I am looking for best practices, and simple solutions that enable to use one spark session across multiple tests.py files.

I would really appreciate any help ! If you need more context, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to use pytest-spark: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-spark/ ?

Comment: you also don't need to get `sql_context` - just use `spark_session.read` instead. `SQLContext` is deprecated long time ago

Comment: I tried it. But it does not seem to work. Do you have a working example ? The documentation is not so helpful.

Comment: https://github.com/alexott/spark-playground/blob/master/testing/src/python/test-pytest-spark.py

Comment: We only need to pip install `pytest-spark` and use `spark_session` as a fixture ?

Comment: yes, that's only a requirement. You can additionally tune Spark session parameters via `pytest.ini` - see example here: https://github.com/alexott/spark-playground/blob/master/testing/pytest.ini#L4